# What REST Api return AGENT.BUILDDIRECTORY value for the given pool in Azure DevOps Server on-prem?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

So I fetched the build definition:

```
$bd = ...
```

It has the pool Id:

```
C:\> $bd.queue.pool.id

90
C:\>
```

Now I can get the pool data with the capabilities using the Url **https://myserver.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/distributedtask/pools/90/agents?includeCapabilities=true**

And I do get a lot of information, but **Agent.BuildDirectory** is not there:

```
C:\> $x = Invoke-RestMethod $Url -UseDefaultCredentials

C:\> $x.value.systemCapabilities[0].PSObject.Properties.Name |? { $_ -match '^Agent' }

Agent.Name
Agent.Version
Agent.ComputerName
Agent.HomeDirectory
Agent.OS
Agent.OSArchitecture
Agent.OSVersion
C:\>
```

Given a valid build definition how can I get **Agent.BuildDirectory** for every on-prem agent associated with it using the rest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following function:

```
function Invoke-ForEachBuildAgent(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$BuildDefinition,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][scriptblock]$Action,
    [pscredential]$Credential
)
{
    function MapShare($AgentComputerName, $RemoteDirectory, $PSDrive, [pscredential]$Credential)
    {
        if ($Credential)
        {
            $Share = "\\$AgentComputerName\$($RemoteDirectory[0])`$"
            $Mapped = $null
            try
            {
                $Mapped = Test-Path $Share
            }
            catch
            {            
            }
            if (!$Mapped)
            {
                New-PSDrive $PSDrive FileSystem $Share -Credential $Credential > $null
            }
        }
    }

    $RelSourceFolderPath = "SourceRootMapping\1a33a8ed-f8fd-4c08-9f44-440ea9f20315\$($BuildDefinition.Id)\SourceFolder.json"
    $PSDrive = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString('N')
    if (!$Credential -and ($env:USERNAME -ne INSERT_THE_DEFAULT_USER_NAME_HERE))
    {
        $Credential = Get-Credential -UserName INSERT_THE_DEFAULT_USER_NAME_WITH_DOMAIN_HERE -Message "Login to access the agents"
    }

    $Url = "$TfsInstanceUrl/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$($BuildDefinition.Queue.Pool.Id)/agents?includeCapabilities=true"
    (Invoke-RestMethod $Url -UseDefaultCredentials).value.systemCapabilities | Where-Object {
        $_
    } | ForEach-Object {
        try
        {
            $AgentComputerName = $_.'Agent.ComputerName'
            $AgentHomeDirectory = $_.'Agent.HomeDirectory'

            MapShare $AgentComputerName $AgentHomeDirectory $PSDrive $Credential

            $Path = "\\$AgentComputerName\$AgentHomeDirectory\.agent".Replace(':', '$')
            $AgentBuildDirectoryRoot = (Get-Content $Path | ConvertFrom-Json).workFolder
            
            if ($AgentBuildDirectoryRoot[0] -ne $AgentHomeDirectory[0])
            {
                Remove-PSDrive $PSDrive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                MapShare $AgentComputerName $AgentBuildDirectoryRoot $PSDrive $Credential
            }

            $Path = "\\$AgentComputerName\$AgentBuildDirectoryRoot\$RelSourceFolderPath".Replace(':', '$')
            if (!(Test-Path $Path))
            {
                return
            }

            $BuildFolderNumber = (Get-Content $Path | ConvertFrom-Json).agent_builddirectory
            $AgentBuildDirectory = [io.path]::GetFullPath("$Path\..\..\..\..\$BuildFolderNumber")
            & $Action -SystemCapabilities $_ `
                -UncAgentBuildDirectory $AgentBuildDirectory `
                -AgentBuildDirectory "$AgentBuildDirectoryRoot\$LastBuildFolderNumber" `
                -Credential $Credential
        }
        catch
        {
            $_.Exception
        }
        finally
        {
            Remove-PSDrive $PSDrive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure it only works for on-prem agents. I will update my answer. Those running agents hosted in Azure do not really need this functionality in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you access the capabilities of the agent from UI, you'll find there is no `Agent.BuildDirectory` capability, so you can not get it from REST API. Also, `Agent.BuildDirectory` is the local path on the agent where all folders for a given build pipeline are created, the format is like `c:\agent_work\_work\1`, so it's different between build pipelines.

You could get this variable from the build pipeline, or check the build log to get the path.

Comment: I want to know its value irrespective to any build. Looking at the build is a problem, because if I have N agents I have to locate N builds - one per agent.

Comment: I modified the question slightly to emphasize these are on-prem agents. I cannot think of a reason why would anyone need this for agents hosted in the cloud.

Comment: I know you mentioned on-prem agents, so you could check the capabilities of the agent from UI, there is no Agent.BuildDirectory capability. I noticed you have found a solution to get the Agent.BuildDirectory value. You could also get the build log and filter the Build.SourcesDirectory, which is `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s`, then get `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`.

Comment: Build log is not good for the same reason as Build - I will have to examine a build per agent. And what if there are no retained builds for some agents?